# Why does adding files to the app directory make the server slow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I cannot seem to find any information on this.

In my app folder (where I have models, views, controllers folders etc) I created a subdirectory app/data where I put about 10,000 files. After that, my Rails development server was incredibly slow.

What is the reason for this? Can I configure Rails to ignore certain files/folders? I take it it's to do with the dynamic nature of Ruby/Rails?

Comment: 10,000 files? What are they for? That's a LOT of files to put into a single directory and will bog down an OS or an app if it has to locate something. Instead, devise and use a directory hierarchy to reduce the number of files per directory, or better, try to put the files into a database and serve them from it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you add a dir directly under `app/`, all files in this dir are **eager loaded** in production and **lazy loaded** in development by default.

Try adding this in `config/initializer.rb`:

```
path = Rails.root + "app/data"
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths -= [path.to_s]
```

This is to remove `add/data` from autoload path.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html
"Please, do not mutate ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths, the public interface to change autoload paths is config.autoload_paths."

Answer (score 1):

Well, previous answer is correct, but as for me it's better to put this stuff somewhere else, because it's definitely not application code and, for example, it shouldn't be added to git.